# Does Intellij have a way to generate a builder class in Kotlin?

Tags: intellij-idea, kotlin, builder

I've always used IntelliJ's "replace constructor with builder" to autogenerate builder from constructor for Java classes. I don't see a way to do this for Kotlin. Is there such a feature that I'm just not seeing?

Comment: Don't know the answer to your question, but I would be surprised if they did have that feature because builders are a clumsy option in Kotlin when we have `.apply()` and default constructor parameters.

Comment: Isnt there a cleaner way to do this either natively in kotlin or with a library like lombok? https://projectlombok.org/features/Builder

Comment: @Tenfour04 Ahh i see now, how .apply() can achieve the same thing, or default constructor args if you need fields to be immutable.

Comment: @Tenfour04 I can't see how "apply" can help with immutable classes. I have the case when I created an immutable class, I want to fill the object in different parts of the method, or even in different method, I don't want to use "copy" method, because it leads to object copying, each time I invoke it. The only solution here is a good old Builder pattern

Comment: @Demwis doesn’t a builder like the OP is describing require mutable properties? Otherwise you’d need an intermediate mutable builder class.